# D3js arc animation not working when wrapping in object

Tags: javascript, object, d3.js

I have found a d3js arc animation code somewhere around here. What i have done in this code is wrapped it in an object so that i can instantiate and create multiple graphs in a single page. But the code is throwing an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'call' of undefined
```

I have created a gist: Please have a look [here](https://gist.github.com/deepakbhattarai/8780444). Where am i going wrong.

Edit: I have updated the code a bit. now i think the error is of the scope:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Array] has no method 'getRandomRange'
```

i have used `self` instead of `this` but it is not working either

Comment: Where exactly is that error coming from?

Comment: it shows `Object #<CircularGraph> has no method 'getAttribute'` on d3.v3.min.js:5

Comment: Hmm, that's probably line 75. I think you don't need the double selection there -- have you tried something like https://gist.github.com/larskotthoff/8781213

Comment: i have tried your code. it is throwing there is no method named `getRandomRange` but i have used `var self = this` and called it with `self`. the problem i am facing is it is not calling method using `self` either.

Comment: Well have you tried adding `var self = this`?

Comment: yes i have done that as well but it is not working

Comment: Hmm, I guess there's no real reason for `getRandomRange` to be part of that object? Could you move it to global scope?

Comment: ok i have kept that in the global scope but another error is thrown showing  `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Array] has no method 'tweenArc`. `self` is not working

Comment: you can do window.setInterval(graph.changeArc.bind(graph), 2000);.. but you have other issues also.. mostly scope 'this` issue

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ZcGPs/ .. couldn't debug all

Comment: @Sarath yeah i am trying to solve that scope issue but i am not getting a clue on what should i do

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsaleem/4KKsU/1/ you want something like this  .. from this example http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5100636

Comment: @Sarath: i was trying the same example of mbstock and was having the problem in arctween scope. i didn't know how to bind object and you did that and perfectly solved my problem. thank you. please post it as an answer.

Comment: @Lars Kotthoff: thank you very much .you helped me to identify the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do `window.setInterval(graph.changeArc.bind(graph), 2000)`,  but you have other issues also.. mostly scope of `this` issue

You can do somehting like [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsaleem/4KKsU/1/)

Answer (score 1):

In the last line, `window.setInterval(graph.changeArc(), 2000);` **graph.changeArc** is a callback to set interval function. So **()** should not be there.

So the correct way to call the function is **`window.setInterval(graph.changeArc, 2000);`**

Comment: I may be wrong but the above stated error is removed once you call the function as a callback.

Comment: window.setInterval(function(){graph.changeArc()}, 2000); also works.

Comment: But eve if i do the other way `setInterval(function(){ graph.selectArc().},2000)` it shows the same error.

Comment: why downvote? error goes away if you act according to answer. Check here http://jsfiddle.net/LhRf3/

Comment: No, it throws some other error related to getAttribute. Do not put a `'.'` after graph.selectArc(). Also, there seem to be conflicts due to the way you pass 'this' around your code.

Comment: but i don't have graph.selectArc() method ? and yeah i am having the conflict by passing this. that's what i am asking?

Comment: You have a changArc method in your code. Also,the error you were getting was because of the way you called setIInterval. I am getting further errors in the code and that is because of wrong 'this' being passed around. The error you mentioned above was not coming from d3 library,but was because of wrong function call on window object. For issue with this,you should post a separate question. I would suggest you try assigning various 'this' in code to different variables,like you did in **var self=this;**.